# Hosting multiple express sites on different domains in RHEL server

Tags: express, rhel7

Business has requested to setup an environment to host multiple Express sites on different domains in the same RHEL 7.2 server with minimal inter-site impact/interference.

We tried using the vhost approach wherein we mapped domains to different shells and then mapped using the below code in server.js which serves as the main entry point for our all Express sites:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path'),
  express = require('express'),
  vhost = require('vhost'),

var app = express();
var virtualHosts = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('vhosts.json', 'utf8'));
virtualHosts.forEach(function(virtualHost) {
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, virtualHost.path)));
app.use(vhost(virtualHost.domain, app));

});

// Listen on port 8082
app.listen(8082);
```

But this approach is not working out as for each of these domains, the same content is being displayed if we browse through host file entry.

Any quick suggestions are highly appreciated?

PS: We are not inclined on using the nginx proxy.

Comment: Please include the content of `vhosts.json` as it is key to answering this question.

Comment: [ 
{
    "domain": "www.example.com",
    "path": "htdocs/example_com"
  },
  {
    "domain": "subdomain.example.com",
    "path": "htdocs/subdomain_example_com"
  },
  {
    "domain": "my.website.com",
    "path": "htdocs/my_website_com"
  },
  {
    "domain": "expressexample.com",
    "path": "htdocs/express_example"
  },
{
    "domain": "www.exampletestdiageo.com",
    "path": "/htdocs/nodejs_com"
  }, 
{
    "domain": "www.nodejssitetest.com",
    "path": "htdocs/nodejs_site_test"
  }

]

Comment: this is the content of the json file